# c program to interact with client

Tags: c

this is a c program (a server that interacts with the client)
i am pretty sure i havent done much wrong

i get an error on compilation[image]

```
   int main(int argc, char **argv) 
    {
    int sock, fd;
    socklen_t client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Socket failed");
        exit(1);
            }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons (SERVER_PORT);

    if (bind ( sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof server) == -1);
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(2);
    }

    listen (sock,1);

    while (1)
    {
        client_len = sizeof (client);
        if((fd = accept ( sock, (struct structaddr *) &client, &client_len)) < 0)
        {
            perror("accepting connection");
            exit(3);
            }
    fprintf(stderr, "\nOpen. \n");
    (send (fd, "\nWelcome!\n", 50, 0);
    check_stats(fd, fd);
            }

        close(fd);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nClose\n");
    exit(0);
    }
```

i have attatched the screen shot, and it seems a minor issues although i cant figure out what!

Comment: It lacks some `#include`...

Comment: Sometimes screenshot really add some fun !

Answer (score 5):

You are not compiling it. When you type: `./server.c` you are trying to run it as a shell script.

To compile it: `gcc server.c` (if you have gcc installed. try `cc server.c` or `cl server.c` if you have some other compiler installed)

To run it: `./a.out`